# Using nullable field in where clause Linq

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I have a table `Salary` where I have a nullable foreign key `programmerId` and I don't know how to write my query.

I get this error

> 'Domain.Abstract.Repository.IProgrammerRepository' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and no extension method 'Where' accepting a first argument of type 'Cbc.Domain.Abstract.Repository.IProgrammerRepository' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

My code:

```
if(entity.programmerId != null)
{ 
    var programmer= repositoryContainer
                    .ProgrammerRepository
                    .Where(entity.programmerId !=null && id == entity.programmerId)
                    .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Any help?

**Update**

```
public partial class Salary : IEntity<long>
{ 
     public long Id { get; set; }
     public int Мonth { get; set; }
     public int Year { get; set; }
     public long? ProgrammerId {get; set} 
     public virtual Programmer {get;Set}
}

public partial class Programmer: IEntity<long> 
{
      public long Id { get; set; } 
}
```

I need to select the programmer where `id == salary.ProgrammerId`

Comment: It's just a syntax issue: you need to pass a lambda (which has one of these `=>` thingies) to `Where`, i.e. `Where(entity => entity.programmerId!=null && id==entity.programmerId)`.

Comment: You should edit your question with description of specific problem, in your case e.g. I need to create query that will return entity A with entity B and description of DB + mapping DB to entities. Otherwise It would be difficult to give you answer. Is it Salary that you want to query? Is it programmer with salary?

Comment: Are you missing a Get() or a similar method on ProgrammerRepository that returns an IEnumerable<Entity> or IQueryable<Entity> ? Like ...ProgrammerRepository.Get().Where....

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use correct lamba expression?
It should look like this:

```
var programmer = repositoryContainer
                     .ProgrammerRepository
                     .Where(p => p.programmerId.HasValue && p.programmerId == id)
                     .FirstOrDefault();
```

Where() is extension method from System.Linq namespace, and it is expecting lambda expression instead of plain expression. Thats why you're getting that error.

Comment: If i understand this lamda expression you says if in Table programmer field programmerId hasValue, but in my case the nullable field is in my Salary table.

Comment: Oh ok, and what entity you need to query and how are they related together? Is it Salary that has programmerId not null?

Comment: public partial class Salary : IEntity<long>
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }

        public int Мonth { get; set; }

        public int Year { get; set; }
public long? ProgrammerId {get; set} 
public virtual Programmer {get;Set}.......

public partial class Programmer: IEntity<long>
    {
        public long Id { get; set; } ....

Comment: So if you want query that will result in Salary objects you should use Salary Repository. Can you describe what exactly you need to query?